# Все ли области включены правильно?

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Мне интересует раздел дискретной математики. Правильно ли все там? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На этот вопрос нельзя однозначно ответить. Каждый классификатор считает, что его классификация лучше других. Например, в английской wiki к д.м. относят 17 пунктов

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относится к программированию. Философия науки не входит в тематику Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что деление математики на разделы крайне условно. Потому что из криптографии можно проследовать в алгебру, например. Из булевой алгебры попасть в диффуры, а оттуда провалиться в топологию.

Короче, деление математики на разделы нужно только в том случае, если вы строите некий целостный курс, по которому будете изучать ВСЮ математику.

В виду сильной связности, математику нужно изучать всю целиком, со специализацией на некоторых отделах. Нельзя выучить только матанализ, не узнав при этом ничего из дифференциальной геометрии и теории меры например. А от теории меры недалеко до топологии.

Comment: Скажи с чего можно начать учить математику для программиста?

Comment: @veter программисты бывают очень разные. Кому-то вот нужна вычислительная геометрия (если писать машинное зрение всякое), кому-то нужна алгебра (компрессоры, криптография), кому-то численный анализ. Вы чего хотите?